# How to trigger paused animation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to trigger an animation that makes the game screen fade to greyscale when the character dies. This is my first game so it is rather simple. I have not been able to successfully trigger the animation. I have not been able to successfully trigger the animation. Online, I found that `document.getElementById("object").animationPlayState = "running"` should work, but it doesn't. This is my game loop and CSS (game is a `<div>` in HTML).

link to full code in codepen (doesn't work properly): https://codepen.io/flyingchicken22/pen/NWgVrJq

CSS:

```
#game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/73/79/26/360_F_173792623_516juhwjkCCZJ9OyesyH7hf7r9zsyH5u.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    animation: deathAnimation 2s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes deathAnimation {
    0%{filter:none;}
    100%{filter:grayscale(100%);}
}
```

Javascript:

```
var gameLoop = setInterval(() => {
    dead = false
    function rockAnimation() {
        rock.classList.add('rockAnimation')
    }
    const knightTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(knight).getPropertyValue('top'))
    const rockLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(rock).getPropertyValue('left'))
    if (rockLeft < 0) {
        rock.style.display = 'none'
    } else {
        rock.style.display = ''
    }

    if (rockLeft < 90 && rockLeft > 50 && knightTop > 79) {
        dead = true
    }
    score.innerText++

    const deathAnimation = document.getElementById("deathAnimation")
    const game = document.getElementById("game")
    if (dead == true) {
        clearInterval(gameLoop)
        document.getElementById("youDied").innerHTML = "YOU DIED"
        document.getElementById("playAgain").innerHTML = "Play Again?" 
        game.classList.add(deathAnimation)
        document.getElementById("deathAnimation").style.animationPlayState = "running"
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Please share a link to see all the code..

Comment: Added all of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return an HTML element that does not exist. Change `document.getElementById("deathAnimation").style.animationPlayState = "running"` to `document.getElementById("game").style.animationPlayState = "running"`

**Try the following snippet**

```js
const background = document.getElementById('game')
const knight = document.getElementById('knight')
const rock = document.getElementById('rock')
const score = document.getElementById('score')
//transfers jump animation to script
function jump() {
    knight.classList.add('jump-animation')
    setTimeout(() => {
        knight.classList.remove('jump-animation')
    }, 500)
}
//When any key is pressed, run jump animation
document.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
    if (!knight.classList.contains('jump-animation') && dead == false) {
    jump(); 
    }  
})
//game loop
let dead



var gameLoop = setInterval(() => {
    dead = false
    function rockAnimation() {
        rock.classList.add('rockAnimation')
    }
    const knightTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(knight).getPropertyValue('top'))
    const rockLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(rock).getPropertyValue('left'))
    if (rockLeft < 0) {
        rock.style.display = 'none'
    } else {
        rock.style.display = ''
    }

    if (rockLeft < 90 && rockLeft > 50 && knightTop > 79) {
        dead = true
    }
    score.innerText++

    const deathAnimation = document.getElementById("deathAnimation")
    const game = document.getElementById("game")
    if (dead == true) {
        clearInterval(gameLoop)
        document.getElementById("youDied").innerHTML = "YOU DIED"
       
game.classList.add(deathAnimation)
        document.getElementById("game").style.animationPlayState = "running"
    }
}, 50);
```

```css
html {
    background-color: black;
}

#score {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
}

#game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/73/79/26/360_F_173792623_516juhwjkCCZJ9OyesyH7hf7r9zsyH5u.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    animation: deathAnimation 2s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes deathAnimation {
    0%{filter:none;}
    100%{filter:grayscale(100%);}
}


#knight {
    height: 100px;
    width: 75px;
    position: relative;
    top: 171px;
    left: 50px;
    background-image: url("https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/f57b5304-de59-49e3-b0f9-cc29a2458425/dcgy8i3-e6dac283-04a7-40e5-a333-cc645e172df7.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2Y1N2I1MzA0LWRlNTktNDllMy1iMGY5LWNjMjlhMjQ1ODQyNVwvZGNneThpMy1lNmRhYzI4My0wNGE3LTQwZTUtYTMzMy1jYzY0NWUxNzJkZjcucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.0LapCzRi5sQjkqzwB5lwWQT_XH1BM4rSMZt7jrflMLk");
    background-size: cover;
}

#rock {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 122px;
    left: 550px;
    background-image: url("http://pixelartmaker-data-78746291193.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/image/da268f06e621b21.png");
    background-size: cover;
    animation: rockAnimation 1s linear;
}

@keyframes rockAnimation {
    0%{left: 500px;}
    100%{left: -50px;}
}

.jump-animation {
    animation: jump 0.5s;
}

@keyframes jump {
    0%{top: 171px;}
    50%{top: 70px;}
    75%{top: 70px;}
    100%{top: 171px;}
}

@font-face {
    font-family: VT323;
    src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap);
  }

#gameName {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: 'VT323';
}

#youDied {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);
    animation: youDied 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes youDied {
    0%{color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);}
    50%{color: black}
    100%{color: rgba(102, 255, 0, 0.993);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="knight"></div>
        <div id="rock"></div>

    </div>
    
    <h1 id="score">0</h1>
    <h1 id="gameName">KNIGHT HOPPER</h1>
    <h1 id="youDied"></h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome, I see that you have another issue. The animation only works for 2 seconds and then the colors go back to normal. Do you know how to fix that or you need help?

Comment: I know how to fix that. Thank you for your help.